# How to remove double quotes from a String without shifting data to next column

Tags: java, regex, opencsv

[image: Input CSV]
[image: Output_WithoutReplace function]
[image: Output_WithReplace function]

I have been provided a CSV file which contains 3 columns (Id, Name, Address) 
Each value of the column is enclosed in double quotes because data contains special character like the comma which is also a field separator (,) Since data is enclosed in double quotes the whole thing is treated as String.

My requirement is I have to read Source provided CSV file and create new CSV file which will have few custom columns with no value in it and most importantly values of the columns should not be enclosed in double quotes and values containing comma should not be shifted to next column.

So far I have tried below code. New custom column is added but double quotes and separator are not getting handled. Any help on how this could be done.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;




public class Demo2 {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File sourceCsvFile = null;
        File finalCsvFile = null;
        sourceCsvFile = new File("C:\\MyData\\Input.csv");
        finalCsvFile = new File("C:\\MyData\\Output.csv");
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";



        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(finalCsvFile));


        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sourceCsvFile))) // read the actual Source downloaded csv file which contains double quotes 
        {
            line = br.readLine();  // read only first line
            String newFileLine = "\"UniqueID\"" + cvsSplitBy + line + cvsSplitBy + "\"IsDelete\"" + cvsSplitBy + "\"Rootpid\"";
            writer.write(newFileLine);   // will be written as first line in new csv
            writer.newLine();  //  go to next line for writing next lines


            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)  // this loop to write data for all lines except headers
            {

                newFileLine = "\"\"" + cvsSplitBy + line  + cvsSplitBy + "\"\"" + cvsSplitBy + "\"\"";
            //[enter image description here][1] newFileLine = newFileLine.replace("\"", "");  // when replace is used double quotes is gone, but then comma(,) within data is considered as new column and so data shifts to next column 
                writer.write(newFileLine);
                writer.newLine();

            }

        }

        writer.close();





    }
}
```

Comment: You should use a CSV parsing/writing library.

Comment: May I ask why a csv file including values with a comma as decimal separator is comma separated? Why not semicolon separated? Removing the double quotes will result in more columns if the decimal separator is not replaced (by a dot for example)...

Comment: @AndyTurner I know about Open CSV but its writeAll method requires ResultSet not String so cannot use that

Comment: @deHaar You are right removing double quotes is resulting in more columns and thats what I don't want. Because for further processing I dont want double quotes.  Like I said field seperator is comma in Source File and I cannot change that.

Comment: What do you mean by "and most imp values of the columns should not be enclosed in double quotes"? Did you mean "and most *importantly* ..."?

Comment: @VikasJ Then you have the possibility of temporarily replace the commas that are between two double quotes by a dot... Maybe that is achievable via regex. but I am not sure... As an alternative, I would naively just remove the outer quotation marks and then split the line by `","`, which will only split between values, not values that are separated by comma.

Comment: @deHaar Thanks that's what I was thinking this might be done in Regex and so I added the Tag, but don't know how, can you please provide an example or if its possible to use regex to meet the requirement in my current code even that will be helpful.